Can Twilio detect a DTMF during a <gather> set to 'dtmf speech' once the user has started talking?
My twilio serverless function supports an interactive conversation  by calling itself as the endpoint, appending results of each twiml.gather in a cookie as the 'conversation' supported by openAI. I'm trying to detect a single digit DTMF during the conversation in case the user wants to indicate a status and end the call.
E.g., "Tell me how your visit was, or press one at any time to request a manager call back... "
There's a likely use case where the user presses one after talking, or even during a <say> prompt.  For the example above, the user could press one during the <say> prompt, before, during or after speaking.
However, my <gather> seems to have Twilio detect speech first, and ignore DTMF. Even though they imply that it can detect both.  I can get around this with various timeouts, e.g., setting different speech_timeout from regular timeout as implied in the docs, but this delays the voice responses and the conversation becomes untenable.
Here is my minimalized test script:


 exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
    let sayThis = "";
    // Initiate the Twilio Response object
    const response = new Twilio.Response();
    response.appendHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

    // Parse the cookie value if it exists
    const cookieValue = event.request.cookies.sessionData;
    const sessionData = cookieValue ? JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(cookieValue)) : null;
    const greetingMessage = "hello, we are testing the system for dtmf detectcion.  Press one or share a sentence about your day."
         console.log("Debug: In function.  Let's begin.");

    // Check if "1" was pressed
    if (event.Digits === '1') {
        console.log("Debug: Digit 1 detected before session data");
        dtmf_one_detected = "yes";   
    }

    if (!sessionData) {
        // This is a new conversation since there is no sessionData yet.
        twiml.say({
            voice: 'Polly.Joanna-Neural',
        }, greetingMessage);
         console.log("Debug: After First Say.");

        twiml.gather({
            speechTimeout: 'auto',
            //timeout: 1,
            speechModel: 'experimental_conversations',
            input: 'dtmf speech',
            action: '/welcome',
        });

        // Set a single cookie with all session data
        const newSessionData = {
            conversation: [],
            phone_number: "1111111111"
        };
        response.setCookie('sessionData', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(newSessionData)), ['Path=/']);

        if (event.Digits === '1') {
          console.log("Debug: Digit 1 detected at first session data");
        }

    } else {
        // Continuation of conversation
        try {
            // Get the user's voice input from the event
            let voiceInput = event.SpeechResult;
         console.log("Debug: in Continue");

            // Update conversation history
            sessionData.conversation.push({ role: 'user', content: voiceInput });

            sayThis = "Great. Here is what I heard" + voiceInput + ". Tell me more?";
            // Generate some <Say> TwiML using the response
            twiml.say({
                voice: "Polly.Joanna-Neural",
            }, sayThis);
         console.log("Debug: After Continue  Say.");

            // Add a new gather for the next user input
            twiml.gather({
                speechTimeout: 'auto',
                //timeout: 1,
                speechModel: 'experimental_conversations',
                input: 'dtmf speech',
                action: '/welcome',
            });

            if (event.Digits === '1') {
               console.log("Debug: Digit 1 detected in conversation");
            }

            // Update the session data cookie
            response.setCookie('sessionData', encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(sessionData)), ['Path=/']);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error in handler:", error);
            twiml.say({
                voice: 'Polly.Joanna-Neural',
            }, "I'm sorry, but there was an error processing your request. Please try again.");
        }
    }
    response.setBody(twiml.toString());
    return callback(null, response);
};



Here is Twilio's example of how to detect both:


app.post('/welcome', (req, res) => {
  const vr = new VoiceResponse()
  const gather = vr.gather({
    input: 'dtmf speech',
    numDigits: '1',
    action: '/menu',
    method: 'POST'
  });

  gather.say(
    'Thanks for calling. ' +
    'Press 1 or say astronaut to hear the names of astronauts on the International Space Station. ' +
    'Press 2 or say joke to hear a joke. ' +
    'Press 3 or say goodbye to hang up.'
  )
  res.send(vr.toString())
})



I'd love to keep my conversation structure and timing, and detect a DTMF press anytime during the conversation. The detection doesn't need to be fast.  I'm ok if the script processes the event after the call has hung up. But adding delays to the gather to wait longer than speechTimeout: 'auto' makes the conversation unusable.
Can Twilio detect a DTMF during a <gather> set to 'dtmf speech' or/and also during a <say>?
Thanks for any advice.
Some things I have tried:
I've tried tweaking the timeout setting different speech_timeout from regular timeout as implied in the docs, but this delays the speech responses too much for the rest of the conversation to be useful.
I also tried a nested gather, but this also (perhaps my code) did not seem to allow the event.Digits to be set or detected. This also cause significant delays in the live phone conversation flow.


const gather = response.gather({
  input: 'speech dtmf',
  speechModel: 'experimental_conversations',
  action: '/welcome',
  timeout: 3,
  numDigits: 1
});

gather.say({
  voice: 'Polly.Joanna-Neural'
}, 'Please press 1 or say sales for sales.');



